# how to prove a set of exponentials is dense

Tags: exponential-function

so there is this thing define as the set of all numbers in the form of $$V=\{\exp(k_0\cdot \exp(k_1\cdot \exp(\ldots k_{n-1}\cdot \exp(k_n)) \mid k_i=\pm1\} $$

I asked my teacher that if I let $n$ approach infinity, would $V$ span the positive reals.  He said that it would probably just be dense over the reals, but he is not sure.  How would I go about proving it?

Comment: All of these numbers are positive and so they cannot be dense in the reals.

Comment: I wrote that if it spans the positive reals, but I can change the definition to include positives and negatives.